# CORS error when Amplifyjs React app makes request to Lambda behind a VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, amazon-vpc

When my aws-amplify react app makes a request to a lambda function it errors out with the message below:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://execute-api.region.amazonaws' from origin 'https://amplifyapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This message only occurs when I configure the lambda function behind a VPC (because I would like to call a redis cluster from that lambda function). When I remove the VPC on the lambda function the error goes away.

I have CORS enabled for all methods for my aws-serverless-express app:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
});
```

Is there something I am missing with the headers? Or is this a VPC configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I need to set up a Public subnet for my natgateway and private subnets for my lambda function per the video below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcRKdEP94jM